# Prove that $\int_0^1 f(x^2)dx\geqslant f\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be twice differentiable. Suppose $f''(x)\geqslant 0$ for all $x\in[0,1]$. Prove that

$$\int_0^1f(x^2)dx\geqslant f\left(\frac{1}{3}\right).$$

I am thinking of using Taylor's Theorem to expand $f(x^2)$ at $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$. But it seems that this makes things more complicated.

Comment: Did you perhaps recently hear about Jensen's inequality in one of your classes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A way to rewrite your hypothesis in a more inequality manner is.

$f(x) \geq f'(t) (x-t) +f(t)$  which holds for $\forall t,x \in [0,1]$

To relate $f(x^2)$ we substitute $x$ with $x^2$ we get $f(x^2) \geq f'(t)(x^2-t) +f(t)$

To get even closer to what we are trying to prove
we integrate this and we get 
$$ \int _{0}^{1 }f(x^2) \mathrm{d}x \geq f'(t)(\frac{1}{3}-t) + f(t)$$

That is $\int _{0}^{1 }f(x^2)\mathrm{d}x \geq \max _{t\in [0,1]}   \left ( f'(t)(\frac{1}{3}-t) + f(t)\right )$

Specifically for $t=\frac{1}{3}$ which gives you the inequality you at stake.